# Issue when creating Extract Connection from SparkSQL (Databricks) to Tableau

Tags: apache-spark-sql, tableau-desktop

I am currently trying to create an Extract Connection from SparkSQL to Tableau. When I use Live Connection it is fine (just slow), and when I try to create an extract, if the table only has 400k rows then it works, but now it's 4 million rows and this error keeps happening:

Error Code: B19090E0
[Simba][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: '[Simba][Hardy] (134) File d2cb4908-8c7e-4271-9182-164e32d231c6: A retriable error occurred while attempting to download a result file from the cloud store but the retry limit had been exceeded. Error Detail: File d2cb4908-8c7e-4271-9182-164e32d231c6: An error had occurred while attempting to download the result file.The error is: [Simba][DriverSupport] (1160) Cannot enable SSL for the connection when connecting to a server that has not enabled SSL. If the server has SSL enabled, please check if it has been configured to use a SSL protocol version that is lower than what is allowed for the connection. The minimum SSL protocol version allowed for the connection is: TLS 1.2.. Since the connection has been configured to consider all result file download as retriable errors, we will attempt to retry the download.'.
Unable to create extract

Can someone help me with this? Many thanks!